# Test if any column of a pandas DataFrame satisfies a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a DataFrame with lots of columns. Now I have a condition that tests some of those columns if any of that column-set is different to zero.

Is there any more elegant way to apply that condition to a subset of columns? My current code is:

```
df['indicator'] = (
    (df['col_1'] != 0) | 
    (df['col_2'] != 0) | 
    (df['col_3'] != 0) | 
    (df['col_4'] != 0) | 
    (df['col_5'] != 0)
)
```

I was looking for something like this pseudo code:

```
columns = ['col_1', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5']
df['indicator'] = df.any(columns, lambda value: value != 0)
```

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the pointing out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ne` is the method form of `!=`.  I use that so that pipelining `any` looks nicer.  I use `any(axis=1)` to find if any are true in a row.

```
df['indicator'] = df[columns].ne(0).any(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case you could also check whether the sum of corresponding columns `!=0`:

```
df['indicator'] = df[columns].prod(axis=1).ne(0)
```

PS @piRSquared's solution is much more generic...

Comment: Keep a lookout for your email for tshirt, mug, and stickers.

Comment: Congrats. Long way to go for me though ;)

Comment: @Matthias, accepting piRSquared's answer will make you two points closer :-D

Comment: Had to wait 11min before I was able to accept it. Next goal: 2.000 ;)

Comment: @MaxU, Congrats, every time I see a user with over ten thousands reputations, I am full of my respect and admire. Thank you and the person like you, you all have shined a lot of people's day.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `min`

```
df['indicator']=(df[columns]!=0).min(axis=1).astype(bool)
```