# drop the row only if all columns contains 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop rows that have 0 for all 3 columns, i tried using these codes, but it dropped all the rows that have 0 in either one of the 3 columns instead.

```
indexNames = news[ news['contain1']&news['contain2'] &news['contain3']== 0 ].index
news.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

My CSV file

```
contain1  contain2  contain3
   1        0         0
   0        0         0
   0        1         1
   1        0         1
   0        0         0
   1        1         1
```

Using the codes i used, all of my rows would be deleted. Below are the result i wanted instead

```
contain1  contain2  contain3
   1        0         0
   0        1         1
   1        0         1
   1        1         1
```

Comment: try `news['contain1']==0&news['contain2']==0&news['contain3']==0`

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison i got this error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison: you're confusing bitwise and `&` with logical `and`. Use `news['contain1']==0 and news['contain2']==0 and news['contain3']==0`

Comment: Related: [Test if any column of a pandas DataFrame satisfies a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652404/test-if-any-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe-satisfies-a-condition), just replace with `df[columns].eq(0).all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for not equal `0` and then get rows with at least one match - so removed only `0` rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df = news[news.ne(0).any(axis=1)]
#cols = ['contain1','contain2','contain3']
#if necessary filter only columns by list
#df = news[news[cols].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   contain1  contain2  contain3
0         1         0         0
2         0         1         1
3         1         0         1
5         1         1         1
```

Details:

```
print (news.ne(0))
   contain1  contain2  contain3
0      True     False     False
1     False     False     False
2     False      True      True
3      True     False      True
4     False     False     False
5      True      True      True

print (news.ne(0).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a pandas dataframe you can sum the indexes with `.sum()`.

```
news_sums = news.sum(axis=0)
indexNames = news.loc[news_sums == 0].index
news.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
```

(note: Not tested, just from memory)

Comment: or u could just do this : df.loc[~df.sum(axis=1).eq(0)] ... reduces the need for drop columns or getting the indexes. just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to filter on the sum of your columns. You can do this by running this code `news[news.sum(axis=1)!=0]`.
Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this.

```
news[(news.T != 0).any()]
```